# How can i debug phone-gap PushPlugin?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using `xmpp/css` push implementation, all is fine at server side but I am not receiving any push on device.

So, i need to debug **PhoneGap** [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

Comment: just confirm first, that device id has been generated or not, otherwise will not get push notification.

Comment: Yeah, device is there. Actually push notification was working fine with old implementation we have but was not reliable. So, we switched to new xmpp/css, now all is fine at server but I need to know how to debug a phonegap plugin? which tools i need to debug a phonegap plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please check whether device id is generated or not at Android App side by checking logs.

If generated, then-
Try to use DevHttpClient Google Chrome plugin.

In that, you need to enter

Request URL : android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Authorization : key=API_KEY

And in body :

```
{
   "registration_ids":["XXX Device ID XXX"],
   "data":{"message":"Push Notification Test"}
}
```

You can check this image:
[image]